# How to force $ajax to wait for data and assign these to a variable?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I have trouble async disable ajax. I have the following code:

```
  function GetDataFromUninorte() {
        link="http://www.uninorte.edu.co/documents/71051/11558879/ExampleData.csv/0e3c22b1-0ec4-490d-86a2-d4bc4f512030";
        var result=
        $.ajax({
              url: 'http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + link +"&callback=?" ,
              type: 'GET',
              async: false,
              dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                  console.log("Inside: " + response);
                }
            }).responseText;
       console.log("Outside: "+result);
       return result;
      }
```

And I get the following result:

["Outside" always runs first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnMM3.png)

As you can see, "Outside" always runs first and the result is undefined and can not process data.

I have already tried
When ... Then
Async = false
passing data as parameters I / O function
and other things, but nothing
:/

*... Beforehand thank you very much

(I am not a native english speaker, I apologize if I do not write well)*

**[Solved]**

Maybe is not the best form, but in the "success:" statement I call a function that receive the ajax response and trigger the rest of the process, in this way I not need store the in a variable and the asynchrony not  affect me.

Comment: Tried `$.Deferred`?

Comment: @SandeepNayak  Nope,  I did not know $.Deferred. I'll try to see what happens, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
function GetDataFromUninorte() {
    link="http://www.uninorte.edu.co/documents/71051/11558879/ExampleData.csv/0e3c22b1-0ec4-490d-86a2-d4bc4f512030";
    var result=
    $.ajax({
          url: 'http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + link +"&callback=?" ,
          type: 'GET',
          **timeout: 2000,**
          async: false,
          dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
              console.log("Inside: " + response);
            }
        }).responseText;
   console.log("Outside: "+result);
   return result;
}
```

Comment: hahaha XD now first answer "outside" and returns "undefined", wait X seconds and then executes the request to show "Inside" with the data, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use callbacks, you can read more [here](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/)

```
function GetDataFromUninorte(successCallback, errorCallback) {
    link="http://www.uninorte.edu.co/documents/...";
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + link +"&callback=?" ,
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: successCallback,
        error: errorCallback
    });
}

function mySuccessCallback(successResponse) {
    console.log('callback:success', successResponse);
}
function myErrorCallback(successResponse) {
    console.log('callback:success', successResponse);
}

GetDataFromUninorte(mySuccessCallback, myErrorCallback);
```

Or you can use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) ([bad support in IE browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises))

```
function GetDataFromUninorte() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        link="http://www.uninorte.edu.co/documents/...";
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + link +"&callback=?" ,
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: resolve,
            error: reject
        });
    });

}

GetDataFromUninorte()
    .then(function(successResponse){
        console.log('promise:success', successResponse);
    }, function(errorResponse){
        console.log('promise:error', errorResponse);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX being `asynchronous` by nature, you need to pass `callback`, which will be called when the `ajax` response is received. You may then access `responseText` from the `xhr` object.

You can also you jQuery `Deferred` and `promise` to get around your problem like below:

```
function GetDataFromUninorte() {
        var defObject = $.Deferred();  // create a deferred object.
        link="http://www.uninorte.edu.co/documents/71051/11558879/ExampleData.csv/0e3c22b1-0ec4-490d-86a2-d4bc4f512030";

            $.ajax({
                  url: 'http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + link +"&callback=?" ,
                  type: 'GET',
                  async: false,
                  dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response) {
                      console.log("Inside: " + response);
                      defObject.resolve(response);    //resolve promise and pass the response.
                    }
                });
        return defObject.promise();    // object returns promise immediately.
          }
```

and then:

```
var result = GetDataFromUninorte();

$.when(result).done(function(response){
    // access responseText here...
   console.log(response.responseText);
});
```

You should avoid making AJAX `synchronous` by setting `async:false` as that will block further interactions on the User Interface.